# Access private transactions(payload or state) on a smart contract using tessera

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, quorum

I am pretty new to quorum/tessera and am trying to set up a small POC with 3 nodes. I followed the [7nodes](https://github.com/ConsenSys/quorum-examples) setup example and similarly deployed 3 nodes on my system using Mysql as the database for tessera. What I want to do is:

Deploy a smart contract(privately) for the 3 nodes and do a private transaction between 2 nodes only (which change a state variable). Now, I understand that quorum maintains a public as well as a private state trie. How can I access the change created by the private transaction between these 2 nodes?

My smart contract is:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

contract SampleContract {

    uint256 num1;
    uint256 num2;
    

    function store1(uint256 number) public {
        num1 = number;
    }
    
    function store2(uint256 number) public {
        num2 = number;
    }

    function getVal1() public view returns(uint256){
        return num1;
    }
    
    function getVal2() public view returns (uint256){
        return num2;
    }
}
```

DeploySampleContract.js

```
var abi = [abi-here];
var bytecode = "bytecode-here";
var simpleContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var simple = simpleContract.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: bytecode, gas: '4700000', privateFor: ["pub-key-of-node2","pub-key-of-node3"]}, function(e, contract) {
    if (e) {
        console.log("err creating contract", e);
    } else {
        if (!contract.address) {
            console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
        } else {
            console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
            console.log(contract);
        }
    }
});
```

I use the following command to deploy:

```
geth --exec 'loadScript("DeploySampleContract.js")' attach http://localhost:22000
```

My query/send file:

```
var abi = [abi-here];
var private = eth.contract(abi).at("contract-address-here");
// console.log(private.store1.sendTransaction(27,{from: eth.coinbase}));
// console.log(private.store1.sendTransaction(28,{from: eth.coinbase, privateFor: ["pub-key-node2"]}));
console.log(private.getVal1.call());
```

I have run the above for both types of sendTransaction (and the transaction is successful, commented them out afterwards) but the value of num1 returned by `getVal1()` is still 0. What is the method to access both the transactions' data/state?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Both transactions are masked!

Comment: 2. Usually, when sending a transaction, you have to asynchronously await for it to complete.

Comment: 3. Same for RPCs (in your code - `private.getVal1.call()`).

Comment: What does being masked mean? And if it is masked then how can I access the changes? Also after waiting for the transactions, the result is the same.

Comment: Masked means you've put `//` before it, so it's not being executed!

Comment: Ohh sorry, I  commented them out afterwards. I ran the sendTransaction command once and then commented it out.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing looks correct.
Basically, if `privateFor` is missing, then the transaction is public. You must specify `privateFor` in order for the transaction to be private. All the nodes specified in privateFor (plus the local node) will become participants in that private transaction.
Any attempt to access the contract, or the state, from a non-participant will return zero.

So I can see that you deployed the contract with `privateFor` set to node2 and node3. I assume you did that on node1, so the contract will be available on all 3 nodes. Therefore all three nodes have the contract available, with an initial value of zero for num1 and num2.
You then call store1() to set the value to 27, but without `privateFor` specified. That is therefore a 'public' call on a private contract and will have no effect.
You then have another call to store1() with `privateFor` set to node2. That will set the value to 28 for node2 (and for the node where you ran it). So only those nodes will see the value of 28.